# Micronaut and PowerMock

Tags: mockito, powermock, micronaut

I am trying to use PowerMock(as i have some legacy static methods) in a micronaut based application. But when I try to run the application all micronaut beans are getting injected as null (and the underlying mocks as well)

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyStaticClass.class, ClassToBeTested.class})

public class TestClass {
    @InjectMocks
    private ClassToBeTested obj1;

    @Mock
    private LegacyStaticClass1 obj2;

    @Mock

    private MicronautBasedBean obj2;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
```

Is there a @PowerMockRunnerDelegate or PorwerMock runner from micronaut (like SpringRunner)
also my @Before doesntt get called to inject mocks in this case

I tried using 
@MicronautTest on the TestClass but then PowerMock is not able to mock static class.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a @PowerMockRunnerDelegate or PorwerMock runner from
>   micronaut?

Not currently, no.  Feel free to file a feature request at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-test/issues.  We welcome pull requests too of course.